# How to deploy 1 instance on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I need to deploy 1 instance of a simple Node.js application on Google App Engine, without any form of scaling.

I have tried doing `gcloud preview app deploy`, but that creates many instances even after I try to shut them down. My goal is to consume minimum resources by running only 1 instance.

I am using the simplest example: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these two lines to your app.yaml file:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

This will disable automatic scaling and set the maximum of instances to just one.

Comment: No it doesn't. Ive tried it but still it's running 2 instances. And I just deployed a log `print('Hello World')` but it's printing 4 concurrences at once. This is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the settings for scaling when your [configure your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). The Hello World example does not provide any scaling settings, so default values apply.