# Run default script without accepting request in App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a nodejs script which starts a stream with a third party and stores the incoming messages in FireStore.

There is no need for incoming requests. But after I deployed my script to App Engine, the script only starts if I call the cloud endpoint. After that, it keeps running (and that is what it should do).

Probably there is a way to start processes by default and also build in something like a auto-restart if it crashes, but I couldn't find it or I am using the wrong search terms :-)

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine is a web-microservice platform. I mean that all (micro) service deployed have to be triggered by an HTTP request.

By the way, you can perform an infinite batch process which stream data.

However, you can set up a [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/) which call an AppEngine endpoint. The max duration is 24H. Link this to a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) to launch every day your 24H-long task. (*In detail, your cloud scheduler has to trigger an endpoint like Cloud Function or AppEngine. This endpoint creates the task in Cloud Task. Cloud Scheduler can't directly create a task in Cloud Task*)

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for your quick reply. I am familiar with cloud functions and scheduler, so that helps. But to me, it feels a bit strange to start a task every 24 hours, which should last for 24 hours. If I run a 'normal' server, it would be possible to set up a listener or a streaming connection (MQTT for example) with another service. Which will last 'forever'. Or if it breaks, it will try to start the stream again.

Isn't this possible with app engine? To just start a service 'forever'?

Comment: I never tested, but with AppEngine flexible it should be possible. The worst point with AppEngine Flexible is there is always 1 instances up (and billed). But, in your case, it's what you want. It should work. Let me know

Answer (score 1):

As Guillaume mentioned, GAE isn't really intended for implementing services like the ones you want to.

However, it's possible to do something similar, simply by configuring a minimum 1 idle instance:

- GAE will start an idle instance for the service automatically, without waiting for a triggering request
- when the idle instance dies accidentally or is terminated because it reaches the end of its allowed lifespan GAE will again start a new idle instance
- when the 1st request comes in GAE will dispatch it to the idle instance, that instance thus becoming active (serving subsequent requests) and GAE will immediately start a new idle instance to have it on standby
- when the only active instance dies GAE won't start a new instance immediately, it'll wait until a new request comes in, which will be like the 1st request
- when traffic is high enough GAE will start dispatching it to the idle instance on standby activating it and again start a new idle instance on standby.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks a lot for your reply. Now we are getting somewhere. For some reason, I thought the standard environment was for always running (minimal 1) instances and the flexible env was for scaling instances from 0 - 99 or even more... I made this change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398216/how-to-deploy-1-instance-on-google-app-engine Next step is to check how I get this done: Instances are sent a start request automatically by App Engine in the form of an empty GET request to /_ah/start.

Comment: I wasn't thinking at manual scaling, but that might work too. Add a handler for `/_ah/start` and reply with a success code to indicate that the instance starts successfully.

Comment: Hi Dan, 

Do I still need to trigger /ah_start every 24 hours, or is there a way to let it run forever?

Regards, Peter

Comment: That's why I wasn't thinking at manual scaling - GAE triggers it with auto/basic scaling.

Comment: I did set it to manual already, it should have 1 instance at all times. See my reply from Sep 26 at 11:49.

Comment: I didn't have the right picture: GAE sends `/_ah/start` for manual scaling as well, no need to do anything, see [Instance scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling).